# Where can I find replacement covers for these vents from 1969?

Tags: hvac, heating, air-conditioning

I recently bought a house built in 1969. After moving in I attempted to close and open vents to direct AC and heat into the rooms that needed it. I quickly experience these vents are hard to open and close, you need to essentially stab these things with a large screwdriver to engage the closing/opening mechanism.

They're 25 inches wide, 5 inches tall, and stick out from the wall a good 3 inches. My question, is there anywhere I can buy replacement covers for these that open and close easier and (in my perfect world) sit flush against the wall? I've tried taking one off the wall and it was a pain, the screws have been painted over several times.

I've attached a picture of the vents below.
[image]

Comment: You will not find flush to the wall that works - if you remove it, you will find that the duct is 2.5-3" out from the wall, and this sits on top of the duct. Normally you just set the dampers to balance the system (and then leave them), so screwdriver adjustment is fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is called a Base Board diffuser.  They come with & without damper. They come in standard lengths, 24" being one of them.  They come in white and brown.  They are available in various styles, heights and depths.  Amazon lists a number of them.  Also Supply House.com stocks several.  The HVAC wholesale houses will stock some and if you can find a salesman who is helpful I'm sure he could round one up for you.  If you go to a wholesale house consider taking the old one with you.  Happy Hunting. P.